# PHP cannot extract JSON from HTTP POST

Tags: php, json, post, file-io, file-get-contents

I have an API endpoint which receives this information:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/",
  "query": {},
  "headers": {
    "x-forwarded-for": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "host": "xxx",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "xxx",
    "content-length": "128",
    "accept": "text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*",
    "user-agent": "xxx",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate"
  },
  "bodyRaw": "{\"registrations\":[{\"userId\":\"xxx\",\"userAccessToken\":\"550a3a10-a3be-4784-89e2-42e7c8865883\"}]}",
  "body": {
    "registrations": [
      {
        "userId": "xxx",
        "userAccessToken": "550a3a10-a3be-4784-89e2-42e7c8865883"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I cannot extract the two parameters. I use this code in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$userID = $data['registrations']['userId'];
$userToken = $data['registrations']['userAccessToken'];
```

I then write the two variables `$userID` and `$userToken` to database; however, both variables are empty

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the dump of `file_get_contents('php://input')`?

Comment: based on your json, the path to e.g. `userId` would be: `echo $data['body']['registrations'][0]['userId'];`

Comment: shouldnt it be `$data['body']['registrations'][0]['userId'];` and `$data['body']['registrations'][0]['userAccessToken'];`? (body index)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some keys in your variables. Also I would recommend adding exception handlers in case php://input throws errors. You can try this:

```
try {
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ), TRUE, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR );
} catch ( JsonException $e ) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
$userID = $data['body']['registrations'][0]['userId'];
$userToken = $data['body']['registrations'][0]['userAccessToken'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. At least the json_decode passes the try-catch, however, the variables are still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution.

```
try {
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ), TRUE, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR );
} catch ( JsonException $e ) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
$userID = $data['registrations'][0]['userId'];
$userToken = $data['registrations'][0]['userAccessToken'];
```

I guess because 'php://input' already returns the request body.

Thanks for your comments and help